# How was the $O(\epsilon ^2)$ term obtained?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

$$\newcommand{\brak}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$$

I'm trying to study Path Integral approach to Quantum Mechanics on my own, during the readings, I came across one part that I'm not certain how it was exactly derived, could use any possible hint and advice.

Consider the quantity: $\brak{x'\mid\exp(-iH\epsilon /\hslash)\mid x} =\int dp \brak{x'|p}\brak{p|\exp(-iH\epsilon/\hslash)|x}$

if we stick to the simple case $H =\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(\hat{x})$, then should be able to reach

$\brak{p\mid\exp\left(-i\frac{\epsilon}{\hslash}\left[\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(\hat{x})\right]\right)| x} = \exp\left(-i\frac{\epsilon}{\hslash}\left[\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(\hat{x})\right]\right)\brak{p|x} + O(\epsilon^2)$

I'm wondering how this $O(\epsilon^2)$ term was obtained? If possible, can someone show me the derivation?

Comment: I think there is a couple of mistakes in your last expression: $p$ and $x$ should not be operators, and $\langle p |x \rangle $ should be outside the brackets (?)

Comment: @caverac you are absolutely right

Comment: The $O(\epsilon^2)$ term is just the second order (and higher order) term(s) of the Taylor expansion for the exponential (the first order term is just 1, which gives you the $\langle p|x\rangle$ part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\langle p | \exp\left( -\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\left(\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + V(\hat{x})\right)\right)| x\rangle \\ &=& \langle p | \exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}V(\hat{x})\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\epsilon^2}{h^2}\left[\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m},V(\hat{x})\right]\right)\cdots|x\rangle \\
&=& \langle p | \exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}V(\hat{x})\right)\left(1 + O(\epsilon^2)\right)|x\rangle \\
&=& \langle p | \exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\frac{p^2}{2m}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}V(x)\right)|x\rangle + O(\epsilon^2) \\
&=& \exp\left(-\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\left(\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)\right)\right)\langle p | x \rangle  +  O(\epsilon^2)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: do you recommend any textbooks for studying path integral approach to QM?

Comment: Feynman's Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals is a excellent book

Comment: That's the one I've been chewing on, but I have trouble following math, I guess my updated question is: any math textbook would give me the complete set of knowledge to understand the math involved in Feynman's book?

Comment: Maybe this is too basic for you, but Introduction to Quantum Mechanics - Griffiths will definitely help you developing some math skills for more advanced subjects in quantum mechanics. In any case, feel free to contact me if you get stuck with this

Comment: I shall have a look immediately